# Could someone explain me the significance of Brouwer's Fixed Point Theorem?

Tags: general-topology, combinatorics

Well, I've been reading the proof of Sperner's Lemma and its use in proving Brouwer's Fixed Point Theorem (including the Coffee stiffing analogy ;-)). But I fail to understand the significance of this theorem. Could someone explain me how it can be applied in other important applications?

Comment: Generalizations of it are used to prove many theorems in PDEs!  It's very important

Comment: Theorems that guarantee the existence of something are always important.

Comment: There is a proof that can be made into an algorithm. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_lemma.

Answer (score 5):

The number of fixed points of a map is one of the easiest topological invariants to define, yet it holds a surprising amount of topological information. For instance, if $X$ is a manifold and $f$ is a a continuous function of $X$ into itself which is obtained by slightly disturbing the identity map of $X$, then the number of fixed points (counted with appropriate multiplicities) is equal to the Euler characteristic $\chi(X)$. For instance, an infinitesimal rotation of the sphere has two fixed points, so the sphere has Euler characteristic $2$. On the other hand, the same argument shows that the Euler characteristic of the torus is $0$. If $X$ is a Lie group, an infinitesimal translation has no fixed points, so $\chi(X)=0$. Thus, this gives us a very concrete, hands-on way of understanding the Euler characteristic, and we get lots of interesting results seemingly for free. Brouwer's result is the first in a long line of many.

Answer (score 4):

Gérard Debreu and Kenneth Arrow used it to prove some results which led to a Nobel prize in economics. I think that is pretty significant in and of itself.

Comment: Yes, it is used to prove existence of equilibrium in general equilibrium theory.